# TypeScript lookup/conditional types and unions

Tags: typescript, union, conditional-types

I have a simple question: Is it possible to obtain a type of a part of a union in TypeScript?

For example, you can often use lookup types like this:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

type Name = Person['name']
```

Now, I'm assuming that it is not possible with unions like this:

```
type Entity = 
    { __type: 'Company', name: string } 
  | { __type: 'Employee', firstName: string };
```

So, is there any way how to obtain a part of a union? Something like this:

```
type Company = DoTheMagic<Entity, { __type: 'Employee' }> 

const company: Company = ...;

console.log(company.name) // OK
console.log(company.firstName) // Compile error
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use the conditional type `Extract<T, U>`. If `T` is a union, the result of `Extract` will be all members of the `T` union that satisfy the constraint `U` (aka, `T extends U`)

```
type Company = Extract<Entity, { __type: 'Employee' }>  
// Same as
type Company = {
    __type: "Employee";
    firstName: string;
}
```

Comment: @Deftomat :)) I do my best

Answer (score 2):

*The correct answer was published by **Titian Cernicova-Dragomir.**
However, I decided to post a complete solution to my wider problem.*

We are working with an ApolloClient and we often receives a unions. Due to strong typing, you need a lot of ugly conditions to access the right properties and keep TypeScript happy.

So, I came up with the following **asTypeGuard** function:

```
function asTypeGuard<Typename extends string>(typename: Typename) {
  return function<Entity extends { __typename: string }>(
    entity: Entity
  ): entity is Extract<Entity, { __typename: typeof typename }> {
    return entity.__typename === typename;
  };
}

const isCompany = asTypeGuard('Company');
const isEmployee = asTypeGuard('Employee');

let entity: { __typename: 'Company'; name: string } | { __typename: 'Employee'; firstName: string };

if (isCompany(entity)) {
  console.log(entity.name);
  console.log(entity.firstName) // Property 'firstName' does not exist on type '{ __typename: "Company"; name: string; }
} else if (isEmployee(entity)) {
  console.log(entity.name);     // Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ __typename: "Employee"; firstName: string; }
  console.log(entity.firstName)
}
```